# Storyboard constraint on tableview cell to match footer content

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uitableview

I'm pretty sure this is an easy question and most likely there is something already on Stackoverflow which has this answered but for the life of me my Googling / searching is letting me down...

(If this is answered already please direct me and I'll happily remove this ...)

So...looking at this screenshot in the Settings app:

[image]

How would I get the table cell label to align perfectly to the footer content? ATM, using the default blue dashed guidelines in Storyboard, the alignment is to the left...applying a constraint that matches (very roughly and very manual) to the footer copy as shown in Storyboard, the alignment is not consistent across screen sizes.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Screenshot of Storyboard below...

[image]

Comment: You want to align the label with cell seperator right??

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq Not so much the separator between cells...more the left alignment of the Label to the Footer copy below. I've added a screenshot of my Storyboard - hopefully that'll explain things more easier... If you need more detail let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a leading constraint to label and change it programmatically to match the footer in cellforrow method